# Why Compiler terminated after one cycle?

Tags: c++

I have a problem when i write this code

```
string x;
float num;
while(true){
    getline(cin,x);
    if(x=="")break;
    cin >> num;
}
```

the compiler terminated after one cycle and print new line

input:`"Hello"` for example and 5.5

Comment: What do you mean by the compiler terminating? Do you mean the program terminates?

Comment: So you input `Hello` followed by Enter, then `5.5` followed by Enter? Or did you input `Hello 5.5` followed by Enter?

Comment: I suspect `cin >> num` will read the `5.5` and then the next `getline` will see an empty Enter and `break`. It's a little strange mixing `getline` and `cin >> ...`.

Comment: i input string line followed by enter then float number followed by enter after that terminated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin >> num` reads the number, but it doesn't read the newline after it. So the next time the loop runs, `getline()` reads the empty line that remains.

You should not mix `cin >>` with `getline()`, it often causes problems like this. Read each line with `getline()` and parse it.